# Cannot Add Django Super User

Tags: django, django-authentication

So I have created an AbstractBaseUser and when I go to add a superuser I get an error:

```
class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):

email = models.EmailField(
    verbose_name='email address',
    max_length=255,
    unique=True,
)
donator         = models.DateTimeField()

USERNAME_FIELD  = 'email'   
objects = UserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email

@property
def is_staff(self):
    return self.is_admin
```

I have only been following tutorials so I do not know exactly what I am doing. I have looked at countless posts on here & documentation and none of it seems to work for me. I just keep getting this error:

```
TypeError: create_superuser() takes exactly 4 arguments (3 given)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What does this code have to do with your error? Where did you call `create_superuser`?

Comment: I just did "python manage.py createsuperuser"

Comment: And when after that do you get this error? Immediately?

Comment: What is UserManager? Is that your own class? If so, you should post it.

Comment: I get the error after typing in both passwords. I've just tried running the server and got an error saying "Manager isn't available; User has been swapped for 'accounts.MyUser': I've renamed my manager to MyUserManager incase of any conflicts but it did not work either

Answer (score 0):

This is the MyUserManager class I have and the MyUser class now points to this as well.

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, date_of_birth, password=None):
    """
    Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

    user = self.model(
        email=self.normalize_email(email),
        date_of_birth=date_of_birth,
    )

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, date_of_birth, password):
    """
    Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
    birth and password.
    """
    user = self.create_user(email,
        password=password,
        date_of_birth=date_of_birth
    )
    user.is_admin = True
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return UserWarning
```

I just ripped this directly from the Django docs so I wouldn't think this is where the problem is, or is it?

Comment: This should be in an edit to the question, not posted as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is indeed in the manager. You've overridden the `create_superuser` method to taken an additional parameter, `date_of_birth`. But the Django createsuperuser command doesn't know anything about that, so it just passes the normal three arguments.

Looking at [the code for the command](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/management/commands/createsuperuser.py), it looks like anything that is in the REQUIRED_FIELDS attribute of the user model will be passed on to create_superuser.

Indeed, looking at the [code you are copying](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example), there is a line that you've missed out:

```
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['date_of_birth']
```